# Store return data from $.post call for later use?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

```
// inside $(document).ready function...

var name = '';

function test()
{
    $.post('/student/get-info', function(data) {
        var student = $.parseJSON(data);            
        name = student.name;
    });

    // use 'name' to do something here or outside of this function
}

// I want to use 'name' later without calling '/student/get-info' again
```

**Edit**: name = ''

**Edit**: The question is the thread title. My code doesn't work. After the post call, name is still empty. That's the problem.

**Edit**: $.getJSON is wrong there, $.parseJSON instead

Comment: my code doesn't work, when alert(name) outside of test function, name is still empty. I think Swaff has a good solution. Why downvote him?

Comment: his solution was down-voted because it might work, but is very bad practice, definitely not the best way and might cause other problems.

Comment: I was not the one who down-voted him by the way - someone else must agree with me

Comment: I got a solution, don't know if it is good. I used $.ajax with async = false for test(). This ensures 'name' is not empty for later use. Thanks user551841 for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare var student within the global scope for it to be accessible elsewhere, rather than inside the document.ready function

Or you can not clutter the global vars until you need function test(){} and you could just remove the var prefix, which would make it global (ie delete var name = 0;)

Edit :: **Plus it should be noted that AJAX is asynchronous, so what you're doing won't work. Add to the call back to do what you want rather than after it (as the student will be 0 still), or stop the call being asyncrhonous**

Answer (score 1):

If you want a variable to be global even outside of the `$(document).ready` then you can initialize it outside of that - maybe just before the `$(document).ready` function.

I think the problem you might be having is that you are checking the name variable later in the code, but before `name` is populated. All the code that depends on `name` should be run after the ajax call retrieves data. So either in the `$.post()` callback function or after a timeout or event that checks if the variable `name` has been populated yet.

Answer (score 0):

If it's all in the `$(document).ready` function, you'll have access to it as it's local to that scope.

Way to provide some context, and actually test your code before asking.